# How can I add an assembly signing file (*.pfx) to my MyGet build?

Tags: assembly-signing, myget

I've recently signed an assembly that I have built with MyGet, but the build is failing because the *.pfx* extension is ignored (for security) in my Git repo.  How can I upload the key file to the MyGet build server so that the build can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their support team, MyGet does not support this.